# Node + Connect + WebSockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am looking for a WebSockets lib/middleware for [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/)

The one I found so far is [Socket.IO-connect](https://github.com/bnoguchi/Socket.IO-connect) however it uses patched version of Connect.

This is an issue mainly due to the separation of patched version of [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) from the main branch.

Can you recommend a good library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a connect middleware for socket.io, and infact it's probably not the best way to go about using socket.io with connect. Here is what I do:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = connect.createServer(
  connect.router(function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/assets/index.html', 'utf8'));
      // above file contains <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    });
  })
).listen(80);

var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('message', function(message) {console.log(message)});
  client.on('disconnect', function() {});
});
```

Comment: `readFileSync` will scale great... gnah, not starting a flame war here.

Comment: I believe in showing someone examples, rather than doing their work for them, which is what you seem to believe in Ivo :)

Comment: @Robin Sure I always post the "codez". Even if I post code at times, I don't post code that's incomplete and bad by design.

Comment: Looks pretty complete to me, and I used readFileSync when building an app with 11k visitors in 3 hours and it held up fine, ignorance is bliss to the hatred of the fools.

Comment: Thanks Robin, this is exactly what I managed to get to on my own (sans readFileSync :)

Comment: Of course, you can just use staticProvider middleware of connect to serve your html, I do it this way to allow myself to set cookies to keep the sessions between reconnections of WebSockets

Answer (score 2):

Right now, it's a bad time for WebSockets, Mozilla and Opera won't ship them with the upcoming versions due to some problems with the protocol and broken proxies, which allow for cache poisoning. It very likely that Google will also drop support until the protocol has been fixed.

So as of now, it doesn't make much sense to search for a middleware as the protocol will change very soon and then you'll have to search yet again, so for now you can just as well use the patched version if you really need to.

For details see:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/
http://blog.pusherapp.com/2010/12/9/it-s-not-websockets-it-s-your-broken-proxy

Comment: It's not a bad time for WebSockets, and certainly not for Socket.IO as it has a multitude of fallbacks to simulate them.

Comment: Uh, sorry. It is? At the moment they're dead, until a new spec surfaces and gets integrated (hint: this will take at least half a year or even more...) also, he was specifically searching for a WebSocket middle ware. Sure all the fall backs still work great, but those are not WebSockets and while Socket.IO tries its best to emulate Socket like behavior for all of them, the user experience still differs from "real sockets".

Comment: @RobinDuckett have you seen the whole FF4 & Opera will not support websockets on release due to security flaws in the protocol. I wouldn't be suprised if chrome follows suite in 9 or a later release. (I would be very disappointed though.)

Comment: I believe there have been a few rebuttal postings on the whole issue. The point is, that you don't NEED to use websockets to do this kind of work.

Comment: The point IS, everything besides WebSockets is not a Socket(and Flash Sockets have their own quirks) dunno what you're doing, but I've done some gaming experiments where even Flash Sockets **sucked**. Maybe it would have been more helpful if the questioner actually stated what kind of application he's creating.

Answer (score 0):

My version of [socket.io-connect](https://github.com/kazuyukitanimura/Socket.IO-connect) should work well.